# Validating user controls regardless of page controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I want to validate my user control whenever postback occurs. This is the property inside usercontrol wish I want to validate:

```
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return DateTextBox.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            DateTextBox.Text = value;
        }
    }
```

The `Text` Property always must have format like "YYYY/MM/DD". I want wherever user add this control to every page, when user submits any button, if the `Text` is not valid, button submit event does not raise. The main problem is that i want this works without altering any page. I means without checking something like `Page.IsValid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding ASP.Net validation controls to your `.ascx` markup code.

Try adding the following code

```
<asp:CompareValidator
    id="dateValidator" runat="server" 
    Type="Date"
    Operator="DataTypeCheck"
    ControlToValidate="DateTextBox" 
    ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid date.">
</asp:CompareValidator>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
    ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" 
    ControlToValidate="DateTextBox" 
    runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="Required!">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

But, the problem with this method is all buttons (Save or Submit) not having CauseValidation=False will try to validate this TextBox.

To overcome this issue you need to

1. If buttons are in the user control add a ValidationGroup to all controls (TextBox, Validation controls, buttons etc)
2. If buttons are in your pages
   add a public property to your control to hold the ValidationGroup and assign this value to all controls and all the buttons that need to validate.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:-

```
 public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return DateTextBox.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                try
               {
                    DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyy/MM/dd",CultureInfo.InvarientCulture);
                    DateTextBox.Text = value;
               }
               catch(Exception ex)
               {
                    //// Code when it does not match format.
               }
            }
    }
```

Comment: This method will not stop the postback